# Div width depending on image width that is inside it

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

CSS help is needed.

I have a div that is floated left, inside it is image that has fixed height and auto width. I want the main DIV width to be exactlly as image width.

```
<div class="item">
   <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/49/Sports_shoes.jpg" alt="" />
   <a href="">Name here</a>
</div>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/szPdR/5/) - You can see that the name is on the right of the image, however it should be at the bottom.

So, is there a way of making DIV class="item" alway to have the width of the image. As you see image width can be different.

**I am looking for cross borwser solution** and this mean display: table-cell; is not the solution, since IE7 -8 does not support it.

*** My jquery script block floating left, help needed

Comment: This seems to be a list of items. So consider `<ul>`, and `<li>` elements instead of DIVs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make the images `display: block`. `<img>` elements are inline by default.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/szPdR/1/

For IE support and other tricky browser use jQuery, see this [FIDDLIE](http://jsfiddle.net/szPdR/6/)

Comment: You can also make the anchor `a` tags `display: block`.

Comment: @AndrewS `width: min-content` on the "item" elements will fix that issue, but it only works (prefixed) in Firefox and Chrome. **Live demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/szPdR/3/

Comment: yeah, but what about iE? How to fix this, since this is the main isue why i post this question

Comment: @AndrewS Yes, you can do it with JavaScript: http://jsfiddle.net/szPdR/4/ I can't think of a CSS solution that would work in IE.

Comment: yeah but it needs some changes. mine code/script is stopping from floating to left http://jsfiddle.net/szPdR/5/

Comment: @AndrewS I don't understand. I've provided you with code that works.

Comment: this? http://jsfiddle.net/szPdR/4/ if YES, then i see that all images are on top of each other

Comment: @AndrewS I've fixed it: http://jsfiddle.net/szPdR/7/ I've delayed the code execution to the page "load" event. Usually, you want to execute JavaScript on "DOMContentLoaded", but here we need to read the image dimensions, so we have to wait for all the images to finish loading.

Answer (score 1):

Do it with CSS

```
div {
    width:auto;
}
```